# Wiki with command line support?

Tags: command-line, wiki

I'm looking for a wiki that can be edited from the web and also a command line client. Any ideas?

Comment: see the answers to [this similar question](http://superuser.com/questions/47413/offline-editable-and-mergeable-wiki).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [jekyll](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll) in github pages as wiki, and everything with git.

is really Great!

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [PMWiki](http://pmwiki.org/wiki/PmWiki/FlatFileAdvantages).  It's based on flat files which can be edited directly from the command line using your favorite editor.

Answer (score 1):

Github just released a [wiki engine](http://github.com/blog/699-making-github-more-open-git-backed-wikis) that can do this and is backed by git.

Answer (score 0):

There is [DokuWiki](http://www.dokuwiki.org/), which also uses flat file storage.